# When is the first appearance of this Pokémon character?

Tags: pokemon

On the left you can see Musashi, Kojirou, and Nyasu (aka. Jessie, James, and Meowth in the English dub).

But what's the name of the other guy and when did he first appear?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's [Mondo](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mondo).

Mondo has never made an appearance within the manga or anime series. The only time he is ever referenced is in [It's a White Tomorrow, Team Rocket!](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/It%27s_a_White_Tomorrow,_Team_Rocket!) - a radio drama broadcast only ever released in Japan. Mondo's imagery comes from the CD's official artwork.